# How to represent typical json information

Tags: ios, json, parsing

Below JSON contains 4 items in an array. If you look at each item it is some what shows incomplete keys. I am unable to figure out how to represent the consistent data in iOS (of any UI design patterns). By looking at the below information somewhat they are interlinked to each other for example parent key value information is same as company key value and also in employees one value is same as name key value. This seems to be very typical.

```
{  
    "arays": [  
    {  
      "company": "Microchip",  
      "parent": "File",  
      "employees": [
        "John",
        "Mike"
      ]
    },
    {
      "company": "Apple",
      "mobiles": [
        "111-111-1111",
        "121-121-1212"
      ]
    },
    {
      "company": "File",
      "parent": "Apple",
      "addresses": [
        "2600 space center blvd",
        "2700 university dr"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "mobiles": [
        "222-222-2222"
      ],
      "addresses": [
        "Time Square, NY"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: If you can't get a full spec of the types of data you're going to get, your code will likely fail at some point in the future. Why do you have guess at what's coming?

Comment: My end goal is to parse the above information. I know how to parse it. But I am guessing the items in the array are interlinked. If that is what happening then what is the best way to represent this kind of information in iOS.

Comment: @johnelemans... that is what i m suppose to do not to fail it. And also my observation says it seems like all those items are interlinked. What's your opinion on this?

Comment: Yes, my guess is that you have companies, people, phone numbers and addresses. make a mehod to hold each of those. Make it possible to connect any of those to any other (adddress belongs to a person, or a company, phone belongs to a person or company, person belongs to a company, company belongs to a company etc).

Comment: Still i am not able to design a generic screen flow for this kind of son structure. I really appreciate if any of you guys can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is really too vague and has too many possible answers. I would suggest you do some reading on data modelling and UI design.